# Iterative Distributed Cross-Validation with Early Stopping

Tags: python, parallel-processing, dask, dask-distributed

To be specific I want to parallelize xgboost cross-validation

Please help me design such Dask application. Let's say I have a dask cluster. I want to do a 10-fold cross-validation for xgboost.

Let's say Scheduler needs to keep track of the current state of the job. It launches 10 xgboost tasks on 10 different workers(for each of the folds), with say 10000 iterations for each task maximum.

After each iteration is finished, there is a callback that reports current metric like rmse. So, worker would send that to Scheduler and receive an answer whether to continue or wrap up.

The main scheduler keeps periodically receiving those updates asynchronously. When all workers report a metric at a particular iteration, the scheduler aggregates them (just calculates mean) and pushes it to the current result stack. It also checks whether the result hasn't been improved in the last say 50 iterations, the scheduler tells all workers to wrap up (maybe at the next communication) and report back the result (which is a tree object).

After it gets them all, it returns all trees (and maybe metrics too).

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like you're describing something similar to Hyperband, which is currently implemented in Dask-ML.  You might want to look at these docs:

https://ml.dask.org/modules/generated/dask_ml.model_selection.HyperbandSearchCV.html?highlight=hyperband

If you want to implement something on your own, some of the pieces for that code may be of use to you as well.  Dask-ML lives on Github at https://github.com/dask/dask-ml

Comment: Hyperband gets really tricky when mixed with tensorflow models, particularly ones that don't support partial fit. Any other remedy for that?